# Is there a way to get a second user to authorize an action without the logged in user seeing their details in the request header?

Tags: security, encryption, authorization, credentials, signing

A strange situation that I am unable to find other people having to deal with. We are using Microsoft AspNetCore.Identity to handle our authentication. Everything is working fine.
The problem is that for a user to perform certain actions, they MUST get another user to 'sign' that action. This act of signing of course requires that other user to use their user name and password to sign the action. 
The issue with this is that the other user's details are readily visible in the request payload. So if I am sneaky, I can open the developer tools in my browser (and hide it), then ask my admin to come and sign my action, and when they have gone i can go to the network tab and see their username and login in plain text! 
Of course this is all over https but still, we can't allow one user to see another's sensitive information. 
How are we to manage to allow a second userB to 'sign' an action for userA while in user A's active session, while removing the capacity for userA to steal userB's credentials??? Any ideas? (Front end is angular.js)

Comment: Is your situration that two person authenticate on the same browser?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's a big rework, but instead of having the "admin" sign the request on the user's machine, the admin could receive a "user A requires this action to be signed, proceed? [ok] [cancel]" on their account, the action would be stored in the database (perhaps temporarily?) & then all of the sensitive information is kept within each user's session with no cross over.

Then the authentication of who is permitted to approve actions can be handled in the backend via standard identity methods.

The user's "Please wait while an admin signs this action" modal (assumption) could then poll an API to determine the status of the action and then proceed once accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I second @justcompile's answer if you need an authorised and authenticated user to sign/confirm the action, more work but the only secure way.

If you just need a second pair of eyes to confirm you could message a private group or slack channel that only "authorised" people have access to with a one-time URL containing a token (that maybe expires after a period of time too).

Assuming admins only access that channel they can follow the link, the app can validate the token and confirm the action.

Saves a second (admin) user logging in on their own machine and the need to build a workflow and UI etc, but again exposes you to risk if nefarious types get access to the channel or the links sent to it.

Depends on your appetite for risk I guess.

Answer (score 0):

another user performs signing action on your local system? and you are sly?
there is no way to protect their password.

use two factor authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The way this would normally be handled is for the user to request an action. This (unsigned) action-request is recorded in the database. The admin user is able to see this unsigned request in their account, and make an (authenticated) request to sign it. The user would be able to see the status of their request, and whether it has been signed yet.